# How to get rid of permision denied while using mv command?

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to move a file from one directory to other by command line.I used this command

```
raghul@raghul-Aspire-5750Z:~/temp/newfolder$ mv copy.txt /temp/
```

I got **error** like this

> cannot create regular file '/temp': Permission denied

Can someone help me to figure this out? I need to move a file from one directory to other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just noticed that you're in a personal directory called `~/temp/newfolder`. Is that the `temp` you're trying to move the file to: your personal one, in which `newfolder` is in? So you want to move the file up one directory?

Then the problem is that your command is missing the 'personal' tag `~`. The command should be:

```
mv copy.txt ~/temp/
```

Comment: You could also have used the "parent directory" notation: `..`. So `mv copy.txt ..`

Answer (score 3):

First of all you are using the copy command `cp`, not the move command `mv`.

Secondly you are trying to copy the file to a new file named `/temp`, ie. a file named `temp` in the `/` directory. This resides in the filesystem's root directory, which is mostly likely owned by root. Unless you have root permissions you can not write to the root directory.

Given that you are naming the file `temp`, I assume that you want to move the file to the `/tmp` directory, for which you will have permission to write to. Do this:

```
$ mv copy.txt /tmp
```

This will work only if you also have write permission on the file `copy.txt` because you need to be able to remove it. If you just wanted to copy the file, just read permission is required.

Otherwise, if you really do wish to move the file to a `/temp` directory, you can use `sudo` to do that, provided that you are set up as a sudo user:

```
$ sudo mv copy.txt /temp
[sudo] password for raghul
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Is it possible to move a file from newfolder to temp?I

Comment: @RaghulM: just updated answer. The key thing is that your user must have permission to a) write to the target directory and b) write to the directory containing the file from whence you are moving it, as well as permission to write to that file so that it can be removed. If you don't you can try using `sudo`.

Comment: @RaghulM: if you are not sure, edit your question with the output of the following commands : `ls -ld /temp`, `ls -ld .`, `ls -l copy.txt`.

Comment: @Raghul - Do you mean `~/temp/`? That is a different directory from `/temp/`. The second is a global directory: the first is in your personal directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving it with sudo command as it seems you don't have permission to move the file.
If you are requested for a password enter the root's password.

Try this:

```
sudo cp copy.txt /temp/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: change /temp to

```html
mv index.text temp
```